# В чем отличие public и assets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, vite

Что такое (public, assets) и что в нем хранить? Зачем нам это?

[image: Фото проекта на viteJS]

Comment: сейчас объясню)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public` - папка в которой лежат публично доступные файлы разого назначения например index.html, hello.html и.т.д. как правило это и есть корень сайта `/`

`assets` - папка в которой лежат ассеты сайта (картинки, скрипты, стили, шрифты) и которая может быть легко переписана компилятором webpack и им подобным без потери важных данных.

`storage` - папка куда пользователи могут например залить видеофайл или автарку но которая так или иначе учавствует в процессе работы сайта. Как правило управляеться backend скриптами.

`static` - папка куда разработчик кладёт ассеты сайта (картинки, скрипты, стили, шрифты). Но которая управляеться именно разработчиком, а не создаёться автоматический при компиляции webpack'ом.

А вообще такое разделение нужно не только что-бы было удобно пользоваться посткомпиляцией, но ещё активно учавствует в правильной настройке кеширования сайта.

Comment: эх блин не успел ответ написать

Comment: старался, старался, а тут такое...

Comment: @PeterKolosov отправь, если ответ хороший, то не жалко плюсик поставить.

Answer (score 0):

> Папка `public` полезна в качестве обходного пути для ряда менее распространенных
> случаев:
>
> -Вам нужен файл с определенным именем в выходных данных сборки.
>
> -У вас есть тысячи изображений, и вам нужно динамически ссылаться на их пути.
>
> -Вы хотите включить небольшой скрипт вне связанного кода.
>
> -Некоторые библиотеки могут быть несовместимы с веб-пакетом, и у вас нет другого
> выбора, кроме как включить его в качестве `<script>` тега.

Более подробно здесь https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder

Папка `assets` используется для хранения изображений, файлов css, файлов шрифтов и т. д. для вашего проекта, практически все, что не связано с кодом.